# How to assign a pixel a value, then get that value's coordinates

Tags: python, random, pixel, getpixel

I'm only a couple weeks into my IT degree and I'm trying to write a small program in Python, I've tried searching for a solution but my knowledge of terminology and concepts is probably limiting my results.  Saying that, I'm trying to find out if it is possible to assign a value to a pixel in a random range, then get the x,y of that value and manipulate it. For example

```
import random
pic=makeEmptyPicture(500,500)
w=random.randint(0,getWidth(pic))
h=random.randint(0,getHeight(pic))
a=getPixel(pic,w,h)
for x in range(getX(a),getX(a+5),1): #this is where I'm stuck.
    for y in range(getY(a),getY(a+5),1): #I need to get the x,y of "a"
        #Do something                    #and manipulate it.
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This doesn't make sense - the coordinates of the pixel you retrieved are of course the `w`, `h` parameters you passed to `getPixel()`.

Comment: I was trying to use  w , h  to generate a 2nd random coordinate for another value to use later on in the program.  I should have provided more information sorry.  I've found the error in this section.  I needed to take the +5 out of the brackets.  Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 0):

The variables `w` and `h` are the (x, y) coordinates.

To manipulate that pixel, I would need to learn about your "picture" object.

First, see what kind of object `makeEmptyPicture` returns. Then look at that object to see if it had any useful functions.

```
pic = makeEmptyPicture(500, 500)
print("type: ", type(pic))
for var in dir(pic):
    print(var)
```

If this isn't enough information, use Python's built-in "help" command.

```
pic = makeEmptyPicture(500, 500)
help(pic)
```

These might give you some good leads. If you're still stuck, post the results, and I'll help you.